# A problem with calculus concerning acceleration of a body.

Tags: calculus

The motion of a specific body is described as the displacement is, $s=t^n$. where the is time and n is an integer.

Now, find the value of $n$ when the acceleration is numerically equal to velocity of the body.  I found out the velocity is, $v= nt^{n-1}$ and acceleration, $a= n(n-1)t^{n-2}$.

The answer in the book is $n=11$ but if the value is put in both then they are not equal..  velocity becomes $11t^{10}$ and acceleration is $110t^9$.

I think I am wrong in determining the acceleration.. Help me if am doing it in the right way.. Thanks

Comment: Presumably they're asking about the velocity and acceleration at time $t = 10$.

Comment: but there was no mention of the time.

Comment: THANK U Bongers..  It was written with an asterisk..